# Get HTML hidden input value in inline jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a value passed from the controller in **jQuery**.
I added a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="Result" value="@Model.Result" />
```

And I tried to get the value in Jquery as follows:

```
$("#Result").val()
```

`Model.Result` has values, but in Jquery it shows it has no value.
I am using inline Javascript.

Comment: Please most more code.

Comment: Have you tried moving your JQuery into a $(document).ready()?

Comment: Open your browser console (F12) and check for errors

Comment: The variable is returning somerthing?

Comment: But why are you using 'inline JavaScript' when you have jQuery? Where does this 'inline JavaScript' appear in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VB92/) and it works perfect. Did you try to put your code into `$(document).ready()`? For example:

```
$(document).ready(function{
  alert($("#Result").val());
});
```

Comment: Please don't use "u" and "ur" on stackoverflow. Also, we wrap small pieces of code between backticks.